# React Native react-native-image-picker, react-native-fetch-blob workaround to clear images taken from camera

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-fs, react-native-fetch-blob

You have probably noticed that `storageOptions: { cameraRoll: false }` parameter is not working on Android when using `react-native-image-picker` library.

Instead it saves pictures taken from camera to a gallery. 
Alternatively, `storageOptions: { path: 'custom_pah' }` works

I used both `react-native-fetch-blob` and `react-native-fs` as well as different solutions from articles and GitHub issues to perform very simple operation of removing shots taken from camera.

If I try to delete an image file, both file management libraries leave an empty thumbnail and do not remove file completely.

When I try to delete the whole folder specified previously in `'custom_path'` param - nothing happens, though the app has storage permissions.

Please be kind and help with the solution, this is a very well known issue, for instance the Telegram APP doesn't save images to gallery, while the rest of major Android apps do.

Thank you!